# How to send a message to a new channel using bot framework?

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am making a bot which is connected to the webchat channel. However, on a specific message entered by the user, I want to send a message to different user on the Directline channel with whom I have already made a connection.

I have the id, name and conversationID of the user on the Directline channel, so I have tried something like this:

```
var msg1 = await result as Activity;       //Message from Webchat channel
IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();

message.From = new ChannelAccount(name: "Bolo", id: "bol24x7");
message.Recipient = new ChannelAccount(name: "Auto", id: "aa24x7");
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: "GxBTy2R7nDq94FEvAvBd5A");
message.ChannelId = "directline";
message.Text = "1234";

var connector3 = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("https://directline.botframework.com/"));

if (msg1.Text == "1234") {
await connector3.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
}
```

However, I get this error:
"Sorry, my bot code is having an issue." What can I do?

Comment: please let me know if my answer was useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Since directline channel is different from the one message came from you need to mark its service url as trusted and then intialize `connector3`, like the following:

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl("https://directline.botframework.com/", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));

var account = new MicrosoftAppCredentials("MicrosoftAppId", "MicrosoftAppPassword");

var connector3 = new ConnectorClient(new Uri("https://directline.botframework.com/"), account);
```